# SELECT command denied to user

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having trouble accessing my database in phpmyadmin. Whenever I run any code that requires SELECT,UPDATE etc.. I get this error:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'a15efe_registr'@'10.10.28.176' for table 'userregistration'
```

In my table userregistration, there exists a user

```
a15efe_registr@10.10.28.54
```

If I search for grants under the user 'a15efe_registr' using

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'a15efe_registr'@'%'
```

I get this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'a15efe_registr'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 10
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `db_a15efe_registr`.* TO 'a15efe_registr'@'%'
```

It seems that I have the correct user but at a different IP address?

Comment: what connection to mysql authorization do you expect your `userregistration` table to have?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the details you've provided, it seems likely you haven't selected the database `db_a15efe_registr` that you're granted access to.

Comment: Hmm I have added the ConnectionString provided by the hosting website and my query string looks something like this:
                   ` queryStr = "SELECT count(*) FROM db_a15efe_registr.userregistration WHERE username = ?username";`